# Stack CSS Transitions using multiple classes without overriding

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to use multiple classes to optionally add transitions.  Instead of stacking, the previous is getting overridden.

```
.container { transition: margin .2s; }
.container.t-padding { transition: padding .2s; }
```

**The problem: Property is overridden rather than stacking**

http://jsfiddle.net/yz2J8/2/ (The problem)

**My temporary solution:  Add the previous transition to the rule**

```
.container { transition: margin .2s; }
.container.t-padding { transition: padding .2s, margin .2s; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfQcp/6/ (My temporary solution)

**What's a better solution??**

How can I avoid having to create tons of rules to combine these?

Comment: I believe your temporary solution will be rather permanent. `;)` That's the way CSS properties and specificity were intended. Unless you want ugly hacks (e.g. nesting elements and applying a transition to each) or use some pre-processor (though I don't know any with a native mixin for this) in the end it will boil down to what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript could be a cleaner solution as you only need to have 1 CSS rule (the original rule).

If you know the position of you're rule you can do the following.

```
//First Save The Original Rule

var originalRule = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].cssText;

//Save also the original Hover Rule

var originalHover = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[4].cssText;
```

Now `originalRule` will contain this:

```
.container{
   ...
   transition: margin .2s;
   ...
}
```

And `originalHover` will contain this:

```
.container:hover{
   ...
   margin: 10px 0;
   ...
}
```

to simply add another transition effect, you can do the following.

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style.transitionProperty += ",background-color";
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[4].style.transitionDuration += ",1s";
```

At this stage, both transitions will take effect.

If you want to only have the original transition, you can either add it manually or simply...

```
//Delete the Rule

document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(3);

//Add the Original Rule Back Again

document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(originalRule,3);
```

If you do so, only the original transition (margin) will take effect, don't forget to also replace the originalHover rule to remove any other effects on hover.

**Note:**

For Chrome

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style.webkitTransitionProperty
```

For Firefox

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[3].style.mozTransitionProperty
```

For IE
`insertRule` and `deleteRule` do not work, there's these ones instead:

```
addRule , removeRule
```

[LIVE DEMO FOR CHROME AND FIREFOX](http://jsfiddle.net/92yNQ/)

Comment: whoa - i'll just create some redundant css classes :P  dynamic css rules are pretty sweet though, i've been meaning to check those out.  thanks for the thorough response