# Multiple transitions with media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries, transition

I know I can create multiple transitions with commas (like `width 1s, height 1s`), but what if I want one in a media query?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #div {
        transition: width 1s;
    }
}
#div {
    transition: height 1s; /* Overrides previous one :( */
}
```

How can I achieve this? Would I have to resort to making 2 media queries (goes up exponentially as original media queries go up)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    #div {
        transition: height 1s;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #div {
        transition: width 1s, height 1s; /* Ugly duplication :( */
    }
}
```

Of course, the problem would be the same with complex selectors instead of media queries.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why do you need different transitions for different screen sizes. Please explain further.

Comment: @Steven Why not? I want transitions specific to different layouts.

Comment: it's unclear what exactly you are trying to differentiate between the two cases

Comment: @Mabedan Does it matter? If I ask a question 'how to use css color' then you will ask me why I want that element green?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack CSS Transitions using multiple classes without overriding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888312/stack-css-transitions-using-multiple-classes-without-overriding)

Comment: @James Wow, that solution isn't better than duplication. Anyway, leave would it work for media queries?

Comment: @bjb568  I think the real answer is in the comment.  Essentially, "sorry, you're out of luck".  I agree the solution on that question is worse than duplicating the values.

Comment: Why don't you just swap the order? Place the div *before* the media query - then it won't override it.

Comment: @Danield Then the media query would override the general rule.

Comment: @James Ok, I'll just wait another 10 years for a solution. Hopefully the site (and my question (and me (and my computer))) will still be there then.

Comment: I should note that this _isn't_ exactly a dup because the other one doesn't work for media queries. (I don't know what "leave would it work" means :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use LESS to do it

https://github.com/less/less-docs/blob/master/content/features/merge.md

```
.mixin() {
  transition: height 1s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    .mixin()
}


@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .mixin();
  transition+: width 1s;
}
```

Comment: Ok, that'll work. It's kind of [big](https://raw.github.com/less/less.js/master/dist/less-1.6.2.min.js), and I'm not using Node.js… Oh, well.

Comment: you can just compile it. Use Simpless, Codekit...etc or the command-line (requires node on your local machine) `npm install less` `lessc input.less output.ccs` then you can use the compiled file. I only use precompilers for my CSS, it makes a lot of things easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

The reason that what you're proposing doesn't work is because `transition`, like other CSS properties, can only take a single value. It doesn't calculate the fact that the earlier transition applied to `width`, so the new one for `height` could just extend it. It replaces the entire value. That's why you're getting the override.

The single `transition` property is actually shorthand for all of the transition properties: `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function`, and `transition-delay`. So you could just target the one part you want to change:

```
#div {
    transition: height 1s;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #div {
        transition-property: width, height;
    }
}
```

You still have to specify both properties in your override, but it does relieve you the trouble of specifying the duration in more than one place.

Also note that the order is important. You'll want to specify the base case first in the document, and then the overrides after that. CSS always reads from top to bottom and gives the later rules precedence over the earlier ones. I think that's why in your first example the height transition was always overriding the width transition. It had nothing to do with the query—it was just because of the order.

Comment: Actually, I most of that. Your solution wouldn't work because the `1s` time was just an example and could be anything. Wouldn't it be better for CSS to treat transition as an array, somehow?

Comment: I thought it was too until recently. I guess it makes sense if you look at CSS properties as single values, but it sure feels like it should be an array.